# How would you construct an injective function that maps $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: functions

If we define rational numbers to be: $\mathbb{Q}=\{\frac{a}{b}|\space a,b\in \mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}\}$(not including $0$ in natural numbers) then we could map $|a|$ and $|b|$ into ordered pairs $(|a|,|b|)$. Defining the ordered pairs that way, in some cases different values of $a$ and $b$ would yield same output e.g. for $a=-1$ and $b=1$ we would get the same ordered pair $(1,1)$ as for $a=1$ and $b=1$ (not a injective function). This is obviously not a good way of solving this problem.
How would you construct such function and write the definition formally?

Answer (score 1):

If the integer is negative, say $\frac{-p}{q}$, then map it to $(2p, 2q)$.  That is guaranteed to be distinct from the encoding of the positive rationals, whose values will all be relatively prime.